# Che cosa significa "tendersi" in questo contesto?

Tags: verbs, meaning

Nel libro *Non ora, non qui*, di Erri De Luca, ho letto:

> Ti ascoltavo e succedeva questo: la tua voce **si tendeva** e dentro di me cominciava la rappresentazione materiale di quello che dicevi. I tuoi racconti mi procuravano immedesimazione fisica. Un bambino preso a schiaffi, tirato per i capelli che avevi visto in strada, diventava carne dentro di me e io ripetevo il suo dolore. Provavo male proprio dove era stato colpito. I miei nervi reagivano alle tue parole con rappresentazioni localizzate, la tua voce li toccava con precisione.

Ho cercato il verbo "tendere" in alcuni dizionari, tuttavia non riesco a capire il significato  dell'espressione "la tua voce si tendeva" in questo passaggio. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: secondo me è usato nel senso di "allungarsi", ovvero quello di "espandersi" o "riempire" (metaforicamente) l'ascoltatore

Comment: Anch'io trovo opaca questa metafora. In prima lettura mi viene da pensare alla corda di un arco o simili (come se la voce si accingesse a scagliare qualcosa), ma poi questa immagine non trova seguito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questa è una figura retorica, una [sinestesia](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/sinestesia_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/), che infatti viene addirittura spiegata dall'autore:
la voce (senso: udito) diventa qualcosa di materiale che si può visualizzare (senso: vista) e che quindi si può tendere, allungare come una molla

EDIT:
L'autore ha scelto ha scelto "*tendere*" (o "*allungare*", che è molto meno elegante) perché vuole rendere l'idea di un tempo dilatato, dove la frase "un bambino preso a schiaffi" (detto in 2 secondi) diventa reale (quindi si trasferisce con una sinestesia sugli altri sensi, visualizzare il bambino, sentire il dolore degli schiaffi e la disperazione.

Nella prima parte c'è la fase "inattesa" (la voce che si "*tende*"), nella seconda parte la conseguenza di questa fase (rappresentazione materiale di quello che dicevi).

Comment: Ho riportato un brano più ampio: così si capisce meglio la seconda parte della frase.

Comment: Quindi, la frequenza del suono diventava più bassa?

Comment: Non bisogna pensare al tono di voce (alto o basso), piuttosto sulla trasformazione di una voce in immagini e tatto. L'autore ha scelto ha scelto "tendere" (o "allungare", che è molto meno elegante) perché vuole rendere l'idea di un tempo dilatato, dove la frase "un bambino preso a schiaffi" (detto in 2 secondi) diventa reale (quindi si trasferisce con una sinestesia sugli altri sensi, visualizzare il bambino, sentire il dolore degli schiaffi e la disperazione).

Comment: Capisco, ma non mi parlare di un'onda sonora che si allunga perché io penso subito al senso fisico di questa rappresentazione.

Comment: Hai ragione, scusa. Editato.